# How to setup auto complete for laravel 5.6 in netbeans

Tags: laravel-5, netbeans

I following step [here](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) to try generate my _ide_helper.php. But I found the _ide_helper.php is not working, but it work if I replace the generated _ide_helper to [this](https://gist.github.com/barryvdh/5227822)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. The cause lies in the generated

```
public static function if($name, $callback)
```

Solution:

- Delete this function in ide_helper.php
- Test Autocomplete (Let Netbeans generate the internal catalogue)
- Now you can revert the file and the autocomplete still works

I don't know, why the same function declaration works in the 5.5 file out of the box. Maybe it has to do with the length of the file, maybe a NetBeans bug.